Suzuki Swift 2021 1.2 Hybrid - Strange Knocking Sound?
Im driving 2021 Suzuki Swift Hybrid, the moment i got out of the dealership with 0km, the engine started to produce strange knocking sound but only when the car is warmed up, when its cold its great. Any advice would be great.
https://youtube.com/shorts/q9jSZCLOZzI?si=_5jrTrgbqyAnTb3s
Things Japan required so far from the dealership:
Changed the injectors and sparkplugs - still the same.
Nothing else was checked.
